# How to use docker-compose environment variables to populate config file

Tags: bash, docker, rabbitmq, docker-compose

I'm new to docker-compose.
I'm trying to understand how can I pass environment variables via docker-compose to populate missing variables values in a config file during `Dockerfile`'s build stage, so in the run phase, I will run the service- `rabbitmq` with its configuration filled with the env variables values.

In docker-compose yml file I have an `env_file:` and also `environment:`, question how can I pass them forward to populate the config file.

Any help, an idea would be greatly appreciated with a simple example of 
course.

Example rabbitmq config file (with env variable which need to be filled with its value for $SSL_PORT):

```
[{rabbit,
  [
    {loopback_users, []},
    {ssl_listeners, [$SSL_PORT]},
    {ssl_options, [{cacertfile,"/etc/rabbitmq/ca/cacert.pem"},
                   {certfile,"/etc/rabbitmq/server/cert.pem"},
                   {keyfile,"/etc/rabbitmq/server/key.pem"},
                   {verify,verify_none},
                   {fail_if_no_peer_cert,false}]}
  ]}
].
```

Comment: See if the article helps http://tarunlalwani.com/post/simple-parameterized-config-files-docker/

Comment: @TarunLalwani: How do you pass environment variables originated from `env_file:` or `environment:` sections to a config file in the docker build stage?

Comment: If you pass it during the build then you need to use build args. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables-build-arg

Comment: @JavaSa: ...but note that if you are trying to generate that configuration during build you are problem giving up a lot of flexibility.  That (generating configuration files) is typically more usefully done at runtime, because the place you are running a container is very often completely different from the place where the image was built. Also, making the ssl port configureable in the container seems like it would be unnecessary: the container network is isolated, and you can use port mapping to expose the service at arbitrary host ports.

Comment: @larsks: Except the port I need to pass in the user and password I want to create for rabbitmq, in this specific example it will go with the default user.
So I still need templating mechanism to populate the conf.

Comment: @larsks: Can you please specify how this can be done on runtime rather than build time with an example?
I would appreciate also example for build time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem can be divided in 2 parts:

1. Inject the configuration values inside the container
2. Let the target software use such configuration values

The first problem is solved via the use of environment variables: as you stated you can either instruct docker to use env files (`--env-file file.env`) or specify single environment variables (`--env VARIABLE=value`) and docker will make them available inside the container.

The second problem has different solution based on the configuration framework used.

For instance if you are using something like [Typesafe config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) or [Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html) you can just put a reference to the environment variable inside the configuration itself and the configuration framework will automatically expand it.

If instead you are configuring a third-party software which doesn't support environment variable expansion you will need to do some preprocessing **before** the target software gets executed.

This is usually done by creating a docker image with a custom [entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint). This entrypoint is responsible of modifying the configuration of the target software expannding the known environment variables and then starting the software.

An example of such an *entrypoint* script could be:

```
#!/bin/sh

sed -i "s/\$SSL_PORT/$SSL_PORT/g" /etc/software.conf

exec $@
```

Modifying a configuration file in this way could be dangerous and error prone so take care when writing such scripts.

**Update**:

If all you want to do is to perform some pre-processing before the original entrypoint start you can follow this simple pattern: Let's say the original entrypoint is called `docker-entrypoint.sh`, all you need to do is to to create `docker-entrypoint-pre.sh` with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Perfom all the needed preprocessing here...

# Invoke the original entrypoint passing the command and arguments
exec /docker-entrypoint.sh $@
```

If you build a docker image using your new entrypoint and start a container with:

`docker run --rm test-image echo "This is a test"`

What will happen is that `docker-entrypoint-pre.sh` will be called with arguments `echo` and `This is a test`. After the preprocessing is done the original entrypoint `docker-entrypoint.sh` will be called with the same arguments thus maintaining the behaviour of the original image.

**Update2:**
In order to add your new entrypoint you have to create a new Docker image inheriting from the original. Lets say that the original image is `rabbit:latest`, you would need to create a `Dockerfile` with the following content:

```
FROM rabbit:latest

COPY docker-entrypoint-pre.sh /docker-entrypoint-pre.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint-pre.sh"]
```

And then build your image with `docker build -t myrabbit:latest .` from the directory containing the `Dockerfile` and the `docker-entrypoint-pre.sh`.

At this point you have a new image `myrabbit:latest` with your preprocessing logic.

Comment: Can you please specify the translation of bellow bash script command, in addition how can I not override my existing rabbitmq `docker-entrypoint.sh` and just to expand it with my own script to be run before that.
Docker-entrypoint.sh is using the configuration so I need to do some modifications before it is launched

Comment: The bash script that I posted as an example just use sed to replace every occurrence of `$SSL_PORT` with the value of that environment variable. This is my goto approach because `sed` is present in many base images. The last line of the entrypoint script is the actual call to start the software. Docker will call the entrypoint script with the final command (with its arguments) as arguments. Given that this is the case it follows that if you want to do some preprocessing, you can just have your entrypoint call the original one. I'll update the answer in order to provide an example.

Comment: Ok I have a new script with preprocessing, how do I override this dockerfile to launch first my preprocessing and then all other instructions: https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/blob/79277042564875d55e4b05a60c65b6eb46651a94/3.6/debian/Dockerfile

Comment: @JavaSa In order to do that you have to create a new Docker image inheriting from the original one and just replace the entrypoint. See the updated answer for details. Also please accept the answer if you find it complete enough.

Comment: Need to pass also rabbitmq server parameter when launching the docker-entrypoint.sh from pre-entrypoint script.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your config file(s) are using the variable `$SSL_PORT` **inside** the container, and you want to pass environment variables from the **host** machine to be used on build, this can be done in your `docker-compose.yml`. YAML supports the use of environment variables, therefore, you can use `environment:` followed by an array of variables you wish to pass to the container during runtime.

For example:

```
version: '3'
services:
  your-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - "SSL_PORT=${PORT_VARIABLE_FROM_HOST}"
```

To trouble shoot and make sure that your variables are in fact assigned inside your container run:

`docker exec -it <container_name_or_id> printenv`

This should list all of the environment variables inside your container

Comment: I need it on build time not run time, which means in `dockerfile` if I do printenv I don't see the environment variable..